# Unable to mount Azure File Storage on Windows startup

Tags: c#, file, azure, storage, startup

I want to mount an Azure File Storage on Windows startup, so it accesible for a scheduled task that execute a Java application for write in it. This in an Azure VM running Windows Server 2016.

I have created a batch file for mounting the drive, but this requires a user logging to execute. The idea is the drive mounts with no need for any user logs in so I can program the task to run on startup as well.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0):

> but this requires a user logging to execute.The idea is the drive mounts with no need for any user logs in so I can program the task to run on
>
> Is this possible in any way?

If I understand correctly, my workaround is that you could have a try create a scheduled task with **login** and also set the Azure VM **Automatically login**.

So that you **no need** to login the Azure **manually** to execute the script. More detail info please refer the the following steps:

1.Add the scheduled task,more detail please refer to [Schedule a Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx)

mount file share demo script

```
Net Use * /delete /y

Net Use X: \\storageAccount.file.core.windows.net\fileshare accountkey /user:account /persistent:yes
```

2.How to set the Azure VM **Automatically login** you could refer to this [blog](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10/)

**Create Scheduled Task**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The automatic login can't be done on a Windows Server VM

Comment: It also could be done on a Azure Windows server VM.  I also test it on my side. You could [remote to the Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon) to set it. And restart the VM, after a while, try to remote it again you could check that the script is executed before you login.